# All homogeneous rings of a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is related to [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27122/why-is-the-coordinate-ring-of-a-projective-variety-not-determined-by-the-isomorph)

What I am wondering is if I have a graded ring $A$ such that $X=Proj(A)$, then is there some specific classification of $B$'s such that $X=Proj(B)$.

I am particularly interested in the case where $A=K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(\text{one homogeneous poly})$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, I considered that but was too lazy. :P